# Not binding variable?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I am going through some extremely basic tutorials as I am just starting out with Erlang from a web background. I have the following file based off [this forum post](http://www.trapexit.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=33463):

```
-module(calc).

-export([test/0]).

test() ->
  X = io:get_line('X: ').
```

However, I do not get the expected results:

```
1> c(calc).
calc.erl:7: Warning: variable 'X' is unused
{ok,calc}
2> calc:test().
X: test
"test\n"
3> X.
* 1: variable 'X' is unbound
```

Shouldn't `X = io:get_line('X: ').` bind X to the user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X` is only visible within the `test` function and there are no global variables in Erlang. All values to be used outside a function needs to be returned to the function caller.

As it happens your `test` function will return the value of `X` as the function result (assignments are expressions => the bound value is the result and the last expression of a function is returned as the functions result). 
So in the shell you could do `X=calc:test().` to bind `X` to the result.

A gotcha with variables, particularly when working with the shell, is that they are *single-assignment*. If you run `X=calc:test().` twice in the shell, but type different data you will get an error the second time!
Use `f(X).` in the shell to make `X` unbound again.

Comment: So the `"test\n"` line in my second block of code is test() returning the value of X, and since program execution halts at that point, X is no longer bound hence the error at 3>?

Comment: @Phillip `test()` returns the value of `X`, but the variable name `X` is not usable in the shell - it is only usable within `test()`. That's why you get an error in 3. You need to do `X = calc:test()` in 2.